# AWK or Sed to extract words

Tags: text, sed, awk

I am not sure how do this, so I need some help, 
I am working on a file and need to extract only some substrings of this file.
Each linea is separated by semicolons ; 
I would only need the first field, and another field. 
Something similar as follows:

Input File:

```
nakamed;   ecd.bat  ;\\DomainD\userhome_n\nakamed;"\\DomainD\userhome_n\nakamed";"\\serverfile66\userhome\nakamed";"Migrated from standalone DFS"
tanreka;   ecd.bat serverfile60_D  ;;
tayljka;   ecd.bat  ;\\DomainD\userhome_t\tayljka;"\\DomainD\userhome_t\tayljka";"\\serverfile47\userhome_d\tayljka";"Migrated from standalone DFS"
taylpoo;   ecd.bat  ;\\DomainD\userhome_t\taylpoo;"\\DomainD\userhome_t\taylpoo";"\\serverfile32\userhome\taylpoo";"Migrated from standalone DFS"
thomcet;   ecd.bat  ;\\DomainD\userhome_t\thomcet;"\\DomainD\userhome_t\thomcet";"\\serverfile32\userhome\thomcet";"Migrated from standalone DFS"
thomdop;   ecd.bat  ;\\DomainD\userhome_t\thomdop;"\\DomainD\userhome_t\thomdop";"\\serverfile66\userhome\thomdop";"Migrated from standalone DFS"
```

Desired Output file:

```
nakamed;   serverfile66
tanreka;   serverfile60
tayljka;   serverfile47
taylpoo;   serverfile32
thomcet;   serverfile32
thomdop;   serverfile66
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this using `sed` :

```
sed -r 's/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+);.*(serverfile[0-9]+).*/\1;   \2/' file.txt
```

Or with `awk` :

```
awk '{print $1, " ", gensub(/.*(serverfile[0-9]+).*/, "\\1", $0)}' file.txt
```

### OUTPUT

```
nakamed;   serverfile66
tanreka;   serverfile60
tayljka;   serverfile47
taylpoo;   serverfile32
thomcet;   serverfile32
thomdop;   serverfile66
```

Answer (score 1):

You could print out the first field by set your semicolon as a separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; { print $1 }' file
```

Comment: yeah you are right. just needed to show where the source comes from. forgot there -f option. yours are much better. couldnt think how to get the second column right now.

Comment: `awk` based solution is simpler and easy to understand than `sed` based +1 for that reason

Comment: `awk '{print $1, gensub(/.*(serverfile[0-9]+).*/, "\\1", $0)}'`

Comment: @sputnick, thanks. didn't know bout gensub() honestly. havent use awk for a while too. but will `print $1` include the first semicolon? nvm, your answer explains them.